# Enterprise JavaScript Tips

Tags: javascript, enterprise

I'm currently writing an article covering tips/tricks/best practices when working with JavaScript within an Enterprise environment. "Enterprise" can be a bit ambiguous so, for the purpose of this article we will define it as: supporting multiple web-based applications within a network that is not necessarily connected to the Internet.

Here are just a few of the thoughts I've had, to get your creative juices flowing:

- Ensure all libraries are maintained in a central, web-accessible location and that all applications reference those libraries (rather than maintaining independent copies).
- Reference libraries by version, guaranteeing new releases won't break your applications (no jquery-latest, use jquery-#.#.# instead).
- Proper namespacing of application code

What tips can you provide to help me out?

Comment: looks more like an announcement than a question ;)

Comment: @Maxym: Sorry about that, I've added a question to the end to make the intent a little more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Test your javascript on the largest DOM size possible. IE6/7/8 will hang based on number of executed VM statements, as opposed to actual run time. Regex and regex jQuery selectors are particularly bad.

Write less. Javascript in particular becomes very hard to manage and debug beyond a certain size set. Breaking up functionality into different external source files can help, but always consider a better method to do what your doing (example: jquery plugin.)

If you're writing a common pattern over and over, STOP. Either create a global method, or if the method acts on a jQuery selector, consider writing your own jQuery plugin instead.

Don't make methods take DOM objects or IDs. Pass in the jQuery object itself, and operate on that. In this manner, you don't force arbitrary DOM constraints on your method (the object passed in might not even be on the DOM yet, or it might not have an ID).

Don't modify prototypes. This breaks libraries/jQuery. Write a plugin or new datatype if you have to.

Don't modify libraries; this breaks upgradability. You can often achieve a similar affect by wrapping the jQuery library with your own plugin and forwarding/intercepting calls, kind of like AOP.

Don't have code execute while the DOM is still loading. This leads to race conditions that you'll only catch on the machines breakage occurs on, and even then it won't be consistent.

Don't style the page with jQuery. It's tempting, but a FOUC gets worse as the DOM grows. Build `.first-child`, `.last-child` etc. in your server pages, as opposed to hacking it in with jQuery.

Comment: Nice hard-coding jQuery into your advice. Do make methods take dom objects where it's applicable. It's fine to execute code whilst the dom is still loading. Manipulating the DOM whilst it's still loading is bad though.

Comment: Rather than passing in a jQuery object to a function, why not make the function itself be a jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 1):

maybe I'll come back and add more... but for now I have just few in my mind:

1) Caching strategies. Enterprise servers are heavy loaded, to serve http requests it is important to know how can you deal with it. E.g. JS can be cached on client side, but you should know how to 'tell ' a client that new version is available.

2) There are different libraries which minify counts of requests to JS files just appending them (based on configuration). E.g. for Java it is [Jawr](http://jawr.java.net/) (just one of). It's better to load 1,2,3 scripts (read 'files') instead of 100 (and this number becomes normal today, in era of RIA). One more nice trick Jawr does, it creates zipped bundles, so when client asks for script server does not need to zip it.

3) Your business logic can be processed by application server (sort of JBoss, GlassFish etc when we talk about java), but JavaScript is static so it can be server by http server (like Apache, or better lighttd, nginx). Again this way you minify server loading (critical for enterprise)

4) libraries like jquery can be loaded from Google CDN (or any other reliable source).

5) use [Yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/), [PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/), [Ajax DynaTrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) to check performance, get ideas to improve etc.

6) try [mod_pagespeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/module.html), it can 'eliminate' jawr, or make powerful company for it

7) one more issue used today is [JavaScript-on-demand](http://ajaxpatterns.org/On-Demand_Javascript) loading

8) [offline storage](http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2007/01/ajax-performance-local-storage.html)

Well, although you've specified topics you are interested in, the area still looks unlimited...